# Mostrar varias categorías en un tema de WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

¡Buenas! Estoy intentando mostrar varias categorías en mi tema hijo de Storefront haciendo uso del shortcode

```
[products limit='3' category='red, blue, yellow' cat_operator='AND' ]
```

pero no me funciona.

¿Alguna forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado!

El problemilla básicamente era que me estaba equivocando de Shortcode (en la documentación no aparece de manera muy clara, la verdad).

Esta sería el correcto:

```
[product_category category='red,blue,yellow' per_page='3' columns='3' orderby='date' order='desc']
```

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar productos de distintas categorías necesitarás hacer uso o bien de algún plugin que permita filtrar y de esta forma crear un shortcode con los productos filtrados por las categorías que necesitas, o bien hacerlo a código con WP_Query.

Para hacerlo con WP_Query sería algo así:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'        => '10',
    'tax_query'             => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'name', //Campo al que consultar el siguiente elemento
            'terms'         => 'red', //Nombre de la categoría
            'operator'      => 'IN' // Valores posible 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms'         => 'blue',
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms'         => 'yellow',
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),
    )
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($products);
```

De esta forma podrás poner tantos array() como sean necesarios dentro del elemento tax_query